# NSDate causing memory leak in ARC project

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsdate

I am working on an `ARC` based `iPad` application(`iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1`).
When I checked the memory leak using instruments, it showed a huge leak in `[_datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];`
Is this leak a known one or not? How to get rid of it? Please help !!!

Comment: try using  [self.datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: Please post screenshots of your Instruments analysis

Comment: @RaviParmar: That's don't make any sense

Comment: Is it the same on device?

Comment: @Andrea ya, I tried on device.

Comment: Are you using iOS 7 beta?

Comment: @cahn No. I am not. I am using ios 5.1.

Comment: PartiallyFinite is correct - not enough info to assist.  Please post detailed output of your analysis highlighting the leak. Heapshot output would be a start.